# How to match non-capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my input string

```
=abc123&
```

I need to match the alphanumeric portion without capturing **=** and **&**.

The solution I found is to use a **non-capturing group** like:

```
(?:=)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

The issue is that this matches

```
=abc123
```

including **=** which I **don't** want to be included.

I tested the regex with http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

You can simply use this.Or

```
=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=&)
```

You can use this and grab the `group 1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/2